# Javascript confirm and CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I'm not sure if this is more of a CodeIgniter question or a Javascript question.

Here is my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function con(message) {
 var answer = confirm(message);
 if (answer) {
  return true;
 }

 return false;
}
</script>
```

Here is my CI:

```
echo form_submit('submit', 'Login', 'onclick="return con("Are you sure you don\'t have a configuration to submit? Please check the checkbox if you do.")');
```

Why am I not getting a confirmation dialog box?  The JS is in my view.  The CI renders the submit button correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use single quotes in your JS:

```
                    // this double quote is causing issues with the onclick assignment.
onclick="return con("Are you sure you don\'t have a configuration to submit? Please check the checkbox if you do.")'
```

You can even see the issue with the color-syntax highlighting from SO

I recommend:

```
onclick="return con(\'Are you sure you don\\'t have a configuration to submit? Please check the checkbox if you do.\')"'
```

Comment: I wasn't sure about the quoting in the full form_submit function and couldn't work, so I moved the message to my JS and it works.

Comment: In `don't` you need to escape the single quote as well as the backslash.  It should be `dont\\\'t`. :-P

Comment: @Rocket.  You're absolutely correct.  Stupid languages within languages.

Answer (score 1):

This code is going to go into an infinite loop because you named your function `confirm` the same as the built in JavaScript `confirm`.

So, in your `confirm` function, when it calls `confirm` it will be calling your function, not the native function.

The native JavaScript `confirm` function returns true or false, so there is no need for your method.

**EDIT**: The issue is when you are calling form_submit.

Change:

```
'onclick="return con("Are you sure you don\'t have a configuration to submit? Please check the checkbox if you do.")'
```

To:

```
'onclick="return con(\'Are you sure you don\\\'t have a configuration to submit? Please check the checkbox if you do.\')"'
```

Comment: That's not the problem. I renamed the function and it still doesn't work.

Comment: The new solution didn't solve the problem.  I copied in your code and I still get no dialog box.

Comment: @shummel7845: The problem is that you need to make sure your quotes are escaped correctly, I need to make sure I know how many '\'s to put in.

Comment: @shummel7845: Try the current version of my answer.  I changed it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your code getting into endless loop?

You've redefined `confirm()` JS function and you're executing you recurrently.

Comment: I renamed it "con" in both places and I still get no dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

[confirm](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php) is a JavaScript function, rename your function

Comment: I did.  That's not the problem.  See above.